# how to make the slot machine spin and give the value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a slotmachine. I am a beginner in Javascript.

I made three slots and then wanted to spin the slot. I used 'setInterval' to spin it.

```
function drawSlot1(){
  var slot1Value = document.getElementById('slotImage1');
  var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  slot1Value.src = "graphics/" + fruitArray[r1] + ".jpg";
}
setInterval(drawSlot1, 100);
setTimeout(slotTimeout1, 2000);
```

and tried with console.log to see the value at slot1Value.

It gave me  all values generated during the interval. similarly, the other two slots are also made in the same manner.
now i want it to give only the last value (value after spinning stops) in all three slots so that i could compare the values generated and use it for scoring purpose as well as activating NUDGE  and HOLD buttons.
How do i do it? Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to make this animation - without knowing what you WANT to use (thirdparty frameworks vs. plain js) it's hard to give a correct answer. Therefore just an idea: Star twith generating the current + the next value and append the images on top of each other. Every other generated image should be again obove the others. All you need to to then is to make it "move down". You will ofcourse need a container with overflow hidden for this. Probably you should also handle the deletion of the already shown images

Comment: I appreciate your answer but, as i have mentioned i am a beginner, your solution is a bit difficult to do for me. May be a piece of code to store value  when interval starts for 0.1seconds and stops after 2seconds as this code say

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer :) your question is not very specific - you have two very different questions actually - one about anymation and one about javascript. therfore it's hard to answer it

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you your problem description right the solution would be to store r1 value (from drawSlotX function) to global, or wider scoped (than drawSlot function) variable.

```
var solt1NumericValue;

function drawSlot1()
{
  var slot1Value = document.getElementById('slotImage1');
  var solt1NumericValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  slot1Value.src = "graphics/" + fruitArray[solt1NumericValue] + ".jpg";
}
```

When you reach spinning end you can check the value of solt1NumericValue. It should store value that was set during last interval call.

And a sample for animating the spin:
https://jsfiddle.net/spwwtzcd/1/

Comment: I think this only solves one part of the quesiton. The second part is about the animation.

Comment: I see you have already suggested solution for this in your comment - thats fine for me. Lets see what question Author will answer.

Comment: will you look at what have i done? This way, you can find out the error in no time and would be a great help for me.

Comment: or just copy the whole code..
does this site support zip file?
or is there any other way to upload code here
? i m new on stackoverflow...

Comment: Try to put your code on https://jsfiddle.net, you have to separate html, css, and javascrpit, then save it and post the link here.

Comment: thanks for guiding me..
i have uploaded the html, scc and js here but could not upload icons and audio 
https://jsfiddle.net/gt91pykb/

Comment: Well i hardly undestand rules of this game (i have never played such machine). What starts the spinning, what is hold and nurge buttons for?

Comment: Neither have I.
i needed to make this game and it was homework from my school..
please make it spin and make winCondition(); work.  (make the value in the slot work so that I coulld compare the slots..may be any function that has code similar to function XYZ.value..I dont know.....thats all i need for now..I will deal with the buttons later.

Comment: I would be glad if you could mark my post as answer for your first question.

Comment: hello.. can you provide me your contact detail @ITMan?

Comment: I have a task detail to share with you and also have some questions regarding it.

Comment: Sorry cant give you my email this is public website. What kind of help you need?

Comment: okay,,, i understand

I need help with the following problem


The thing is about database and it is assignment for my java programming module...
I wonder if you could help me..

Comment: What do you expect me to do?

Comment: how to make database/?

Comment: Well that's  broad topic. Depends on expected architecture. I think this kind of help is far beyond stackoverflow idea. Sorry, cant help you with that.